# What is the most efficient way to traverse a tree in Python?

Tags: python, tree, traversal

Assuming I have a list of objects that have the following fields

**parent**

**value**

and this defines a tree structure, similar to a directory tree.

I want to traverse the list in a pre-order fashion. What's the most efficient way?

Normally, in other (more imperative) languages I would iterate the values, finding the ones with no parents, then for each, iterating again for every object whose parent is the one I'm currently looking at and so forth, but is there a cleverer way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would first create a more suitable data structure -- capturing the link from a parent to its children:

```
children = {}
for obj in tree:
    children.setdefault(obj.parent, []).append(obj)

def preorder(root, children):
    yield root.value
    for child in children.get(root, []):
        for value in preorder(child, children):
            yield value

for root in children[None]:
    for value in preorder(root, children):
        print value
```

You could also use `collections.defaultdict` here.

Comment: I think the could would be nicer without special casing `obj.parent is not None` in the traversal. It's less code, faster and also can handle a forest instead than a tree (`children[None]` is the list of all tree roots).

Comment: Excellent! I would add that you could change:
   
def preorder(root, children,depth):
  
    yield [root.value,depth]
  
    for child in children.get(root, []):
  
        for value in preorder(child, children,depth+1):
  
            yield value
  
and in that way you could see not only the pre-order result but also how deep every node is. Note that the first call should be preorder(root,children,0) Thanks a lot! **Edit**: Urgh. code looks really messy when replying.